# What are the actions that take place when we browse an ASPX page?

Tags: asp.net

When we request an aspx page from the browser what are all of the files that will be downloaded to the client browser and what will run on the client and server?

Comment: Also this property can say allot runat="server". You can add it at certain tags like the <form> tag well if it there it won't else it will.

Comment: @Mythje :What does that mean or rather say ?

Comment: Well if that is specified it will runat server .. if not it will not be runned at the server. It's really simpel don't think to hard about it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get all details

i recommend you to install **[firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/nl/firefox/addon/1843)** and check the site on the mozila firefox will give you all detail.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This will depend on the ASPX page. For example if this page represents an HTML document that is eventually returned to the client (after processing it on the server) and this document references external javascripts, CSS, images, ... all those external resources will be downloaded by the client browser by sending additional HTTP requests (assuming obviously that they haven't been cached by the client browser in which case they will be served from the client cache).

Answer (score 2):

Well you'll be given the requested HTML page along with any linking data used within it -- images, stylesheets, javacascript, active x objects, sound, etc.... Take a look at your Firebug's NET tab to see exactly what is being retrieved along with the page...